# Conversion of Poisson distribution to Negative Exponential

Tags: probability-distributions

A country bus driver picks up passengers randomly and independently at a mean rate of $\ 12$ per hour.

The time at which he picks up his first passenger is $\ T$ hours. Explain why

$$\ P(T < t) = 1 − e^{−12t} ~for~ t > 0.$$

**Attempt**

Let's say the driver picks his first passenger at $\ t$ hours. Then it is reasonable to say that before $\ t$ hours he had $\ 0$ passengers.
$$\ P(T<t) = 1-Po(12t)  $$
$$\ P(T<t) = 1-e^{-12t}\frac{(12t)^0}{0!}  $$
$$\ P(T<t) = 1-e^{-12t} $$
$\ t$ has to be greater than $\ 0$ since negative time doesn't exist (at least in this context).

So$$\ P(T < t) = 1 − e^{−12t} ~for~ t > 0.$$

Is this explanation correct? If not, can somebody explain why?

Comment: Writing things somewhat more rigorously, let $N_t$ denote the number of passengers arriving between the times $0$ and $t$, then $N_t$ is Poisson with parameter $12t$ and $$P(T<t)=P(N_t\ne0)=1-P(N_t=0)$$ and one can conclude. Which is basically your idea...

Comment: @Did So my explanation makes sense right?

Comment: Quotes: "somewhat more rigorously", "basically your idea".

Comment: Lol; Thank you very much.